# Collect integer and non-integer powers at the same time

Tags: expression-manipulation

Imagine we have an expression that contains both integer ($y$, $y^3$, $y^8$ etc.) and non-integer powers ($y^{1+\alpha}$, $y^{2\,\alpha}$, $y^{2+3\,\alpha}$) of the variable $y$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $\alpha>0$.

Simple example

```
expr = (-1 + (-1 + x) y) (2 + x y + y^α);
```

I want to rewrite this as

```
-2 + (-2 + x) y + (-1 + x) x y^2 - y^α + (-1 + x) y^(1 + α)
```

A more complicated expression, closer to what I have in reality:

```
expr=(-1 + (-1 + x) y + (-1 + x - x^2) y^2) ((1 + x)^4 (1 + y^2 a2[x] + 
    y^α sna[x])^2 ((1 + (-1 + x) y) (1 + 
    1/2 (-1 + x) x (-1 + (-1 + x) x (6 + x (-8 + 3 x))) y + 
    y^α sna[x]) (1 + 1/2 (-1 + x) x (1 + (-1 + x) x (-14 + x (-8 + 21 x))) y + 
    y^α sna[x]) + (1 +1/2 x (-1 + x (35 + x (-76 + x (23 + (46 - 27 x) x)))) y + 
    y^α sna[x]) (3 + 1/2 (-4 + 5 x - 3 x^2 - 20 x^3 + 73 x^4 - 78 x^5 + 27 x^6) y +
    y^α (3 + 2 (-1 + x) y) sna[x])));
```

where `sna[x]` is some real function of another variable `x` that we do not care about.

As in the simple example - I want to `Collect` all powers of `y` - both integer and non-integer, so the final expression will be something like

$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\,a_n(x)\,y^{n}+\sum_{k=0}^{K}b_k(x)\,y^{k+\alpha}+\sum_{j=0}^{J}c_j(x)\,y^{j+2\,\alpha}+...$ and so on depending on what is the highest multiple of $\alpha$ in an exponent, for some integers $N$, $K$, $J$.

I tried

```
Block[{$Assumptions = α > 0 && α ∈ Reals}, 
 Collect[expr, y, Simplify]]
```

and

```
Block[{$Assumptions = α > 0 && α ∈ Reals}, 
 Collect[expr, {y, y^α}, Simplify]]
```

but they don't work.

**UPDATE:** Possible solution. Taking the more complicated example, then we do

```
Block[{$Assumptions = α > 0 && α ∈ Reals}, 
   kek = Collect[expr, {y, y^α}, Simplify]];
kekList = List @@ kek;
Block[{$Assumptions = α > 0 && α ∈ Reals}, 
   kek2 = If[StringContainsQ[ToString[Exponent[#, y]], "Max"], 
       List @@ Collect[ExpandAll[#], y^α, Simplify], 
       Collect[ExpandAll[#], y^α, Simplify]] & /@ kekList];
kek3 = SortBy[Flatten[kek2], Exponent[#, y] &];
```

and `kek3` is what I want. A quick check on the exponents

```
Exponent[kek3, y]
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, α, 2 α, 3 α, 4 α, 1 + α, 2 + α, 3 + α, 4 + α, 5 + α, 6 + α, 7 + α, 8 + α, 1 + 2 α, 2 + 2 α, 3 + 2 α, 4 + 2 α, 5 + 2 α, 6 + 2 α, 7 + 2 α, 1 + 3 α, 2 + 3 α, 3 + 3 α, 4 + 3 α, 5 + 3 α, 1 + 4 α, 2 + 4 α, 3 + 4 α}
```

I am not going to post what `kek3` is itself, as it is very long. The above also works with the simple example.

Now, this is the brute force way that is not efficient. What is the `Mathematica` way to do it, as my real expressions are way longer and this will take centuries to evaluate.

Comment: Could you perhaps come up with a simpler expression to work on, and show the *exact form* (not the general formula) you would like it transformed to?

Comment: @MarcoB I added a simpler example

Comment: Comes close: `In[42]:= expr = (-1 + (-1 + x) y) (2 + x y + y^a);
Collect[expr, {y^a, y}, Factor]

Out[43]= -2 + (-2 + x) y + (-1 + x) x y^2 + y^a (-1 + (-1 + x) y)`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried that. Is there a way to specify a general form, like when one does a replacement `someExpr/.{x^(1+k_):>x^k}` for example.

Comment: Could do that but only if the forms you are after are explicitly in the input. Check for example `In[57]:= expr = (-1 + (-1 + x) y) (2 + x y + y^a);
Collect[Expand@expr, {y^a, y^(a + 1), y}, Factor]

Out[58]= -2 + (-2 + x) y + (-1 + x) x y^2 - y^a + (-1 + x) y^(1 + a)`

Comment: I should note that the desired general form is in conflict with the specific example, in terms of treating "mixed" powers such as `y^(1+a)`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It is late here, so I might be missing something, but doesn't the simple example correspond to $a_0=-2$, $a_1=2-x$, $a_2=-(1-x)x$, $b_0=-1$ and $b_1=-(1-x)$. 
As for the comment before the note - I know that in the simple example case I can just write the explicit powers, but my real life application has very complicated expressions with hundreds of terms, so I need something automated

Comment: The general case has powers in `y^a` with coefficients that have nested powers in `y`. There is no mixing of the integer powers and integer multiple-of-`a` powers.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I am not sure I really understand what you are saying. I rewrote the general formula. The simple example is what I want. The general formula is a mathematical way of writing it - that is obviously not unique due to commutativity, distributivity and so on.

Comment: I think the requirement changedfor the general case. the last time I looked it was as I described in prior comments. Now it is not. It is unrealistic to expect people to foresee such changes. For what it is worth, the earlier requirement would be the easier to meet.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok, I didn't tell you what all the objects in the general formula are, but they are in the worst case scenario real numbers, hence nothing has changed. The old formula was
$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\,a_n(x)\,y^{n}+y^{\alpha}\,\sum_{k=0}^{K}b_k(x)\,y^{k}+y^{2\,\alpha}\,\sum_{j=0}^{J}c_j(x)\,y^{j}+...$, which is equivalent to the new one.
I also edited my post with a possible solution that you can copy paste to see exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following do what you want:

```
expr=(-1+(-1+x) y) (2+x y+y^α);
Collect[expr, y^_.]
```

> -2 + (-2 + x) y + (-x + x^2) y^2 - y^α + (-1 + x) y^(1 + α)

and:

```
expr=(-1 + (-1 + x) y + (-1 + x - x^2) y^2) ((1 + x)^4 (1 + y^2 a2[x] + 
y^α sna[x])^2 ((1 + (-1 + x) y) (1 + 
1/2 (-1 + x) x (-1 + (-1 + x) x (6 + x (-8 + 3 x))) y + 
y^α sna[x]) (1 + 1/2 (-1 + x) x (1 + (-1 + x) x (-14 + x (-8 + 21 x))) y + 
y^α sna[x]) + (1 +1/2 x (-1 + x (35 + x (-76 + x (23 + (46 - 27 x) x)))) y + 
y^α sna[x]) (3 + 1/2 (-4 + 5 x - 3 x^2 - 20 x^3 + 73 x^4 - 78 x^5 + 27 x^6) y +
y^α (3 + 2 (-1 + x) y) sna[x])));

res = Collect[expr, y^_.];
Short[res, 5] //TeXForm
```

> $-16 (x+1)^4 \text{sna}(x) y^{\alpha }-24 (x+1)^4 \text{sna}(x)^2 y^{2 \alpha }-16
>    (x+1)^4 \text{sna}(x)^3 y^{3 \alpha }-4 (x+1)^4 \text{sna}(x)^4 y^{4 \alpha
>    }+\langle\langle 30\rangle\rangle +(x+1)^4 \left(\frac{333 x^{12}}{2}-726 x^{11}+911
>    x^{10}+470 x^9-\frac{4537 x^8}{2}+2235 x^7-887 x^6+105 x^5-\frac{99 x^4}{2}+59
>    x^3-\frac{33 x^2}{2}-2 x-8 \text{a2}(x)-1\right) y^2+(x+1)^4 \left(15 x^6+2 x^5-95
>    x^4+124 x^3-47 x^2+2 x-1\right) y-4 (x+1)^4$

If you want an output where the powers of α are pulled out, you could do:

```
Short[Collect[expr, {y^(_. α), y}], 5] //TeXForm
```

> $\left((x+1)^4 \left(15 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^9-44 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x)
>    x^8+11 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^7+127 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^6-263
>    \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^5+262 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^4-140
>    \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^3+33 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x) x^2-\text{a2}(x)^2
>    \text{sna}(x) x\right) y^8+(x+1)^4 \left(-\frac{63}{2} \text{a2}(x) \text{sna}(x)
>    x^{15}+\langle\langle 31\rangle\rangle +6 \text{a2}(x)^2 \text{sna}(x)\right)
>    y^7+(x+1)^4 (\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle ) y^6+\langle\langle 3\rangle\rangle
>    +\langle\langle 1\rangle\rangle +(x+1)^4 \left(45 \text{sna}(x) x^6+\langle\langle
>    9\rangle\rangle \right) y-16 (x+1)^4 \text{sna}(x)\right) y^{\alpha }+\langle\langle
>    14\rangle\rangle$

Here's a version where I set all of the coefficients to 1:

```
Collect[expr, {y^(_. α), y}, 1&]
```

> 1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + y^6 + y^7 + y^8 + y^9 + 
>    y^(4 α) (1 + y + y^2 + y^3) + 
>    y^(3 α) (1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5) + 
>    y^(2 α) (1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + y^6 + y^7) + 
>    y^α (1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4 + y^5 + y^6 + y^7 + y^8)

Comment: It is what I want and is faster than what I proposed in my question. Do you think it is possible to speed this up?